# How to make text in the center of list item?

Tags: html, css

This is my work that I did. The thing is I can't make the text in the center of the `ul` item.

```css
.fc-list-content {
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.fc-list-content:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.fc-list-a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <a class="fc-list-a">
    <li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 1</span</li>
  </a>
  <a class="fc-list-a">
    <li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 2</span</li>
  </a>
  <a class="fc-list-a">
    <li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 3</span</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have markup errors, `<a>` is not permitted directly under `<ul>`.

To center the text just add `text-align: center` to `ul` or `li`. I also changed `list-style-position: inside` so the bullets will be centered too.

```css
.list-group {
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.fc-list-content {
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.fc-list-content:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.fc-list-a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="fc-list-content"><a class="fc-list-a"><span class="content">ABC 1</span></a></li>
  <li class="fc-list-content"><a class="fc-list-a"><span class="content">ABC 2</span></a></li>
  <li class="fc-list-content"><a class="fc-list-a"><span class="content">ABC 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center;` to `.fc-list-content`

```css
.list-group {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.fc-list-content {
 height: 32px;
 margin-top: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
  .fc-list-content:hover {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .fc-list-a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <a class="fc-list-a"><li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC</span></li></a>
  <a class="fc-list-a"><li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 2</span></li></a>
  <a class="fc-list-a"><li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 3</span></li></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'r DOM it's w3c: you want a list of link, not some peace of link in some link.

After that, a simple text-center should did it.

```css
.fc-list-content
{
 height: 32px;
 margin-top: 10px;
text-align:center;
}
.fc-list-content:hover
{
 background-color: orange;
}
.fc-list-a:hover
{
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">

    <li class="fc-list-content"><a class="fc-list-a"><span class="content">ABC</span></a></li>
      <li class="fc-list-content"><a class="fc-list-a"><span class="content">ABC</span></a>
      <li class="fc-list-content"><a class="fc-list-a"><span class="content">ABC</span></a>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center
```

```css
.fc-list-content
{
 height: 32px;
 margin-top: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.fc-list-content:hover
{
 background-color: orange;
}
.fc-list-a:hover
{
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">

    <a class="fc-list-a"><li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC</span></li></a>
        <a class="fc-list-a"><li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 2</span></li></a>
        <a class="fc-list-a"><li class="fc-list-content"><span class="content">ABC 3</span></li></a>
   </ul>
```